# Problema con 2 formularios en una misma página laravel (Creo que en Laravel Auth está el problema)

Tags: laravel-5, oauth

Tengo dos formularios en una misma página, en este caso en un encabezado (Un menú), el primero es un cuadro de búsqueda y abajo tengo el otro, un form para hacer logout (El que incluye laravel Auth).

Yo asumo que el conflicto se presenta con laravel Auth, ya que al colocar el cuadro de búsqueda en el encabezado de la vista login no envía los datos y si quito el cuadro de búsqueda funciona, igualmente pasa donde tengo el "Logout".

Estos son los códigos:

---------- Form Search -------------------

```
<form id="search" method="get" action="{{ route('blog.search')}}" >
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
  </div>
<form/>
```

------------- Form Logout -----------------

```
<form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
@csrf
</form>
```

Comment: Has probado añadiendo el token ***@csrf*** en tu formulario de buscar como tienes en el de logout? que te muestra por consola ?

Comment: Si, igualmente no funcinó... Alguien me dijo que para las peticiones get no es necesario el token, es cierto?

Comment: Lo resolví, para el campo de busqueda utilicé  laravel collective y funcionó bien. Gracias

Comment: @Joe ¿podrías poner el código con la solución? Puedes responderte a ti mismo y seguro que ayudará a alguien que tenga algún problema similar. Gracias.

Comment: @fly ya lo publiqué

Comment: Me alegro que hayas solventado el problema. La documentación oficial de Laravel recomienda declarar el token ***csrf*** en cualquier formulario de tu aplicación, esto verifica que el usuario que está realizando la solicitud a través del formulario es el correcto. Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias, la ventaja de laravel collective es que ya tiene el token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo solucioné, para el campo de busqueda utilicé laravel collective:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'search', 'method' => 'get']) !!}

<div class="input-group">
{{ Form::text('search', null, ['id' => 'search', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Buscar']) }}
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

El formulario de logout lo dejé igual